# How to change git checkout to original

Tags: git, git-clone, git-fetch

I cloned a software with git clone.

```
git clone https://github.com/BinPro/CONCOCT.git
```

And then

```
cd CONCOCT
git fetch
git checkout SpeedUp_Mp
```

Then I got this message.

```
Branch 'SpeedUp_Mp' set up to track remote branch 'SpeedUp_Mp' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'SpeedUp_Mp
```

Then I put

```
sudo python ./setup.py install
```

Now I want to make it into 'origin' as before.
So I put

```
git fetch
git checkout origin
```

Then I get an error message

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
concoct/cluster.py
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

What can I do? How do I commit changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the original version of the branch,
checkout to a new branch, delete branch with the problem in local

```
git branch -d SpeedUp_Mp
git fetch --all
git checkout SpeedUp_Mp
```

else, you could checkout all the changes you did

```
git checkout .
```

Comment: Hi @BRjava, your answer seems to work. What I've done is , $git checkout . 
$git fetch --all
Fetching origin
$git checkout origin
It now gives me Note: checking out 'origin'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

HEAD is now at 38d2d86... Slight update of readme

Comment: It seems that it is working. Have I done alright? Thank you!

Comment: @SuminKim what you have done is, you have reverted all the changes made to your branch before committed.
so branch goes to the original state.
Could you mark this as answer then

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!